# I want to have one group manage membership of another group in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, security, groups, security-trimming

I want to have group A manage membership in both group A and group B. How do I set that up? I have group A managing its own membership, but I can't figure out how to have group B's membership managed by group A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the group A as the owners of group B. It's in the group settings. Go to the group like you would to add someone, then Settings -> Group Settings [image]

Comment: Great idea! I'll try it out and let you know. Thanks! :)

E: It worked! I don't know why i was overthinking it. Thanks again.